# Changing the state of one component from another component in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have the code below, and what I wish to achieve is to change the state of `Tabscreen` from one of the screens in `TabNavigator`. But way in which I am currently trying to do this, with a global function to set the state, simply does not work, with the error `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setstate')`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, Text, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {Container, Header, Icon, Left, Body} from 'native-base';
import Timeline from './Timeline';

const Mainscreen=TabNavigator(
  {
      Main:{
        screen: Timeline,
        navigationOptions:{
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Icon name='home' style={{color:tintColor}}/>
        }
      },
      Search:{
        screen: props => <Container><TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>globalStateUpdate()}><Container style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(0,132,180,0.5)'}}></Container></TouchableHighlight></Container>,
        navigationOptions:{
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Icon name='search' style={{color:tintColor}}/>
        }
      },
  }
);

function globalStateUpdate(){
  this.setState({
    header:<Text>Search</Text>
  });
}

class Tabscreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      header:<Text>Home</Text>
    };
    globalStateUpdate = globalStateUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header hasTabs >
          <Left>
            {this.state.header}
          </Left>
          <Body/>
        </Header>
        <Mainscreen/>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabscreen;
```

How can I do this? React-navigation is extremely important to my application and I cannot remove that. I believe Redux is something that solves this but it seems overly complicated for just a single change of text, which is all I need.

Comment: Try `<Mainscreen globalStateUpdate={globalStateUpdate} />` and then on your Screen object, inside of the TabNavigator try `onPress={props.globalStateUpdate}` - if not I apologise, just a stab at the problem before I reproduce the code locally.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the reply, doing that removes the error but the text still does not change.

Comment: You need to change your constructor to `this.globalStateUpdate = globalStateUpdate.bind(this);` and then `<Mainscreen globalStateUpdate={this.globalStateUpdate} />` - Here's an example using React https://codesandbox.io/s/0qm840ln30

Comment: @Dan this does not work, it gives me an error similar to last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the function from your `TabScreen` to other screens to update `TabScreen` state.

```
const Mainscreen=TabNavigator(
    {
        Main:{
            screen: Timeline,
            navigationOptions:{
                tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Icon name='home' style={{color:tintColor}}/>
            }
        },
        Search:{
            screen: props => <Container><TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> props.screenProps.globalStateUpdate({header:<Text>Search</Text>})}><Container style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(0,132,180,0.5)'}}></Container></TouchableHighlight></Container>,
            navigationOptions:{
                tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Icon name='search' style={{color:tintColor}}/>
            }
        },
    }
);


class Tabscreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            header:<Text>Home</Text>
            globalStateUpdate: newState => this.setState(newState)
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header hasTabs >
                    <Left>
                        {this.state.header}
                    </Left>
                    <Body/>
                </Header>
                <Mainscreen screenProps={{globalStateUpdate: this.state.globalStateUpdate}} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `<Mainscreen {this.state.globalStateUpdate} />` is picked up as a syntax error so I changed it to `<Mainscreen globalStateUpdate={this.state.globalStateUpdate} />` . Rest of the code was changed exactly as you did. Now it gives the error `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'props.globalStateUpdate')` . Could you please help?

Comment: Ok, maybe I will accept the props if we pass state through screenProps in <Mainscreen />. I have updated my code. Please check.